# how to maintain the data different sections with different data dynamically in swift3?

Tags: json, swift3

I'm working on dynamic form, it has 3 sections with different data like below code.

```
[
    [
    "note",
    "control",
    confirm,
    confirm
],
    [
    "condition",
    select,
    select,
    "note",
    "control",
    confirm,
    confirm,
    confirm
],
    [
    "tab",
    "note",
    "text",
    checkbox,
    "control"
]]
```

Total 3 sections, each section having different elements how can I divide the data with each different section. Based on each string to design UI.
When I'm tap each section it will be show the data.

Help me please

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: each section having  {
    "note",
    "control",
    confirm,
    confirm
} But I want to show the data in dynamically with different arrays with sections

Comment: sorry! it's an array's of array not dictionary.